# Is there a way to share my ECR repository across my organization or across different accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-iam, amazon-ecr

I want to achieve this **without having to push it individually** in the accounts with cross account policy enabled. Is there a way to just mention the image uri path in my lambda function of other accounts so that it picks up my docker image from the origin account.

My image already resides in one of the account, lets call it ACC A. Now i want to use the same repo in ACC B, without having to push that image again in ACC B.

Answer (score 4):

I normally use resource based policies for services like ECR or S3 when I need to allow access for all the accounts within the organization.

This is achieved by using the **"AWS:PrincipalOrgID"** IAM condition, here is a read-only access example for it.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ReadonlyAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "ecr:DescribeImageScanFindings",
                "ecr:DescribeImages",
                "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:ListImages"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:PrincipalOrgID": "<YOUR-ORGANIZATION-ID>"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is the full Terraform equivalent of how to achieve this

```hcl
resource "aws_ecr_repository" "example" {
  name = "example"
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ecr_readonly_access" {
  statement {
    sid    = "ReadonlyAccess"
    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "*"
      identifiers = ["*"]
    }

    condition {
      test     = "StringLike"
      variable = "aws:PrincipalOrgID"
      # This is our organization-wide identifier which can be found after
      # log-in to AWS: <https://console.aws.amazon.com/organizations/home>
      values = [aws_organizations_organization.this.id]
    }

    actions = [
      "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
      "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
      "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
      "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
      "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
      "ecr:ListImages",
      "ecr:DescribeImages",
      "ecr:BatchGetImage",
      "ecr:DescribeImageScanFindings",
    ]
  }
}

resource "aws_ecr_repository_policy" "ecr" {
  repository = aws_ecr_repository.example.name
  policy     = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ecr_readonly_access.json
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Cross Account Method**

First add `ecr:GetAuthorizationToken` permission in your `Account B` Lambda IAM role for authenticating to ECR repository.

```json
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken"
                ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then, in `Account A`, add a policy similar to the following in your `ECR repository (in Permissions)`. The below policy allows AWS account `111111111111` to push and pull image from/to your ECR repository. Replace `111111111111` with your Account B AWS account number

```json
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCrossAccountPush",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:PutImage",
                "ecr:UploadLayerPart"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I tried to follow it but I ended up with error -  ClientError: API error (404): pull access denied for 11111111111.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/demo-repo, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: User: arn:aws:sts::<account-no>:assumed-role/demoinput-role-16hufnye/SageMaker is not authorized to perform: ecr:BatchGetImage on resource: arn:aws:ecr:ap-south-1:257169079289:repository/demo-repo. How do i use ecr login command with boto3 in my lambda function?

Comment: Use `subprocess` module or try with `docker` module

Comment: This worked out for me, but get authorization was not needed apparently.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the blog post in the other answer, and found that it is just as simple as adding

```json
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "share_dev",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "ecr:DescribeImages",
      "Condition": {
        "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
          "aws:PrincipalOrgPaths": [
            "o-<org-id>/r-<root-ou-id>/ou-<sub-ou-id>/*"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In the permission set of you repository.

Now any account/role that is in the `sub-ou-id` organization can describe images.

Answer (score -1):

[This blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/sharing-amazon-ecr-repositories-with-multiple-accounts-using-aws-organizations/) walks you through the setup (it focuses on ECS as the consumption service for the image but the same concepts would apply to Lambda)

Comment: This involves creating a cloudformation template and everything. I just want my sagemaker in my ACC B to pick up image from ACC A, and all this is mentioned in my lambda code.

Comment: I am unclear how you think you could achieve this with full transparency (i.e. without enforcing access policies). That would mean anyone could access images in *your* ACC A.